# Local image does not fire onload event even though the function is placed before the change in 'src' value

Tags: reactjs

I need to draw an image to canvas after loading it from a React component. I have used the componentDidMount function to reference the canvas and then tried to draw a local image using the Image() class. The onload event performs the drawing function after the image has loaded but it only works on online images. How do I make it work for local images stored in the src folder?

I have already tried placing the onload call before changing the src values of the variable.

```
const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var background = new Image();
// background.src = './assets/background.png';
background.onload = () => {
  alert ( 'This does not fire , only works for online images' );
  context.drawImage ( background , 0 , 0 );
}
background.src = {background_image};
```

My component is as follows :

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <canvas ref='canvas'/>
    </div>   
  );
}
```

Comment: BTW This code is for a create-react-app.

Comment: Where did you placed background image code?

Comment: @Justcode The background image is placed in the assets folder which is in the src folder i.e., the same place where the js files are.